# InversifyJS: Inject typed class

Tags: node.js, express, inversifyjs

I am developing an typescript-based API with inversify-express-utils, where I am using dependency injection. I am new to inversify and express and read a lot of tutorials and documentation. But I am pretty unsure if inversify supports a dependency injection with typed-classes. I would like to have a typed middleware-class which extends the BaseMiddleware from inversify-express-utils: Something like MyMiddleware<T> where T is a joi-validation scheme, which I want to use on certain endpoints. Currently I know I have to declare my types in a notation like:

```
export const TYPES = {
    MyMiddleware: Symbol.for('MyMiddleware'), ...
}
```

and then bind them into the container which some options like:

```
container.bind<MyMiddleware>(TYPES.MyMiddleware).to(MyMiddleware).inTransientScope();
```

So, is it possible to use some typed classes with the container and if yes, how can I do that?